# Rails passing authorization token to Android app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json

I built a rails API to send send a token upon authorization.

The problem is that I can't seem to grasp how I am going to pass the token to the Android app once the user is authorized.

I was successful in passing in email and password to the rails server as JSONObjects.
(went to this website: http://andrewgertig.com/2010/07/android-and-ruby-on-rails/)

Should I try to accept the token generated from rails as JSONObjects or XML data?

I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accept the api_token from Rails backend as JSONObjects during HttpPost for login. If any fellow beginner has questions regarding this, feel free to message me.